# Temporary Views in Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql

Can one create temporary views inside a postgres function? If so, can an example be given? I cannot think of what else might be the issue.

```
CREATE FUNCTION personInfo(c text)
     RETURNS TABLE (p int, s int, n int) AS
     $$
          CREATE TEMP VIEW PeopleWithSkills AS (SELECT P.pid, PS.skill
          FROM Person P, PersonSkill PS
          WHERE P.pid = PS.pid);

          CREATE TEMP VIEW PeopleWOSkills AS (SELECT P.pid FROM Person P EXCEPT Select PW.pid FROM PeopleWithSkills PW);

          CREATE TEMP VIEW SkillsPerPerson AS (SELECT PeopleWithSkills.pid, COUNT(*)
          FROM  PeopleWithSkills
          GROUP BY(PeopleWithSkills.pid));

          CREATE TEMP VIEW zeroSkills AS (SELECT P.pid, 0 FROM PeopleWOSkills);

          CREATE TEMP VIEW allSkills AS (SELECT * FROM zeroSkills UNION SELECT * FROM SkillsPerPerson);

          SELECT allSkills.pid, worksFor.salary, allSkills.count
          FROM allSkills INNER JOIN worksFor
          ON allSkills.pid = W.pid
          WHERE W.cname = c;
          
     $$language sql;

Gives the following error:
ERROR:  relation "allskills" does not exist
LINE 19:           FROM allSkills INNER JOIN worksFor
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your actual code. Or did you do ` CREATE TEMP VIEW "allSkills" ...`? To me it looks like an identifier quoting issue.

Answer (score 0):

After long research I found a solution, can you please follow the given reference link and update your function according to that. The problem is with TEMP view creation inside the function.

These are the steps needed to follow in order to achieve the solution.

1. Function that will create a temp table if not exists yet
2. Function that will call the function from p.1 and return all records from temp table
3. view that will have the same name as temp table which will select from a function defined on p.2
4. functions that will be used in triggers defined on view from p.3
5. statement level and row-level INSTEAD OF trigger(s) defined on a view from p.3 which will call functions from p.4

https://chumaky.team/blog/postgres-persistent-temp-tables